# Another JavaScript Bug: adding transition to element causes extra 0s

Tags: javascript

Using this lines I tried to add transitions to the element:

```
transition.style.transform = 'translateY(0)';
            transition.style['-webkit-transition'] = 'opacity 0.9s ease-in-out';

            setTimeout(() => {
                type == 'showContainer' ? transition.style.opacity = 1 :
                                          transition.style.opacity = 0;
            }, 100);
```

But it sets the transition like this:

```
element.style {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    transition: opacity 0.9s ease-in-out 0s;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

The extra 0s is included and ruins the transition!!! How can I fix this?

I just want to add a simple opacity transition ;(

Answer (score -1):

Couple of things:

To set the style property with it's css name, use [`style.setProperty(property, value)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty). To set it directly with javascript, the properties have different names, such as `backgroundColor` as opposed to `background-color`.

Why do you use a timeout? You can directly set the opacity and the transition. There will be no timing issues.

Use `transition` instead of `-webkit-transition`. It is [compatible](https://caniuse.com/?search=transition) with every browser. And can be directly set on style property.

Comment: My issue is something else, even with your approach I set `transition: opacity 0.9s ease-in-out 0s;` . the last 0s cause the issue...